# Convert a hash string to a formatted number?

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to  output prettier numbers from my [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) template in GeoServer:

```
     <#list features as feature>
       <#if attribute.name="lon" || attribute.name="lat">
                <td>${feature[attribute.name].value?round}</td>
       <#else>
                <td>${feature[attribute.name].value}</td>
       </#if>
     </#list>
```

If I take out the `?round`, I get things like "-121.469166666667".  I simply wish to format that number a bit, say by rounding it to 4 decimal places.

I've tried a couple things:

```
${feature[attribute.name].value?number}
${(feature[attribute.name].value)?number.string("0.0000")}
```

But those complain of "Expected hash.", so I'm feeling like it's just a syntax issue of conveying the string in the hash to the `?` operator correctly, so that I'm actually executing methods on the string... but that has stumped me.

Comment: Try: ${((feature[attribute.name].value*10000)?round)/10000}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always want 4 decimals:

```
${feature[attribute.name].value?string("0.0000")}
```

If you want at most 4 decimals, then `?string("0.####")`

The `?number` part is only needed if `value` is a string. In that case you should write `[...].value?number?string("0.0000")`. There's no such thing as `?number.string`, hence the "expected hash" error message.